# How to make PowerLine HomePlug adaper sets to work together

Tags: wireless-networking, powerline-networking

I got some LAN network to extend and I cannot drill walls. It is quite big school building. I decide to extend it using HomePlug AV, Powerline adapters. I have two sets of: ASUS PL-N12 300Mbps adapters and one set ASUS PLAC56 AV2 1200 adapters I need to make 3 WIFI access points using those adapters.

I noticed that the more adapters in electrical network the more problems with network initialization and network interrupts from time to time. I noticed also that input adapters cannot be in the same electrical plug.

Right now I have two sets working on different floors, but it seems to be not solid solution (initialization problem). And I need to add third one on the one of floor that I have adapters already. Third one adds even more uncertainty to my solution.

How to make those adapters work together? Is there any other solution that doesn't require wall drilling?

Comment: Are these adapters crossing circuit breakers? I have seen issues similar to this, when I called tp-link thinking they were defective they told me to make sure the adapters we're on the same electrical circuit. It's worth a shot.